# TestNG- `is-config` attribute in XML Report

Tags: testng

In my project, I need to parse the default xml report(**testng-results.xml**) generated by the surefire plugin. For that, I need to identify the **test methods** from the xml report.

On analysis, I found that one 'is-config' attribute is present for the non-test methods. Can any one help me, what is the meaning of this attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods annotated with @BeforeXX and @AfterXX are treated as configurtion methods, coz they can be used to configure the environment, before the actual test begins.
So, I believe the is-config is set to true for these methods in the results xml, while for test methods which would ideally contain your test, this param would not be set.

Answer (score 1):

It's for configuration methods (@Before*/@After*).